# Distinct with several conditions

Tags: sql, distinct

I have a dataframe with several columns:

`SightingID, PA1, PA2, Area, PlotID`.

Different SightingIDs (with PA1, PA2 and Area associated) have the same PlotID.I would like to select one SightingID (i.e., one row) per PlotID (i.e., obtain a DF with unique PlotID) from several conditions.

If there are several SightingIDs for the same plot then select the SightingID by -

1. First selecting the SightingID which have PA1=O, if there are several SightingID with PA1=0 with the same PlotID
2. then select the one with the maximum value for Area.
3. If for one PlotID, there is no SightingID with PA1=0, just take the one with the maximum value for Area.

I came with that

```
SELECT SightingID, PA1, PA2, PlotID, MAX(Area) FROM DF GROUP BY PlotID
```

and I obtained distinct PlotID with the SightingID which had the highest Area value but I don't know how to incorporate my first condition.

I know I should use the `Distinct`fonction but I don't know how to make the conditions with it.Sorry if it's a bit confusing but if someone could help me, that would be great. Thanks

Comment: Distinct with several conditions = **Group by** ..usually !

Comment: Could you please format this for better readability? It's a little difficult to get through this wall of text while trying to grok your situation.

Answer (score 0):

Group By can be used instead of distinct.  Depending on the SQL engine, it may even rewrite the query plan to be the same.

The following two queries are semantically the same:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a, b FROM foo;
```

and

```
SELECT a, b FROM foo GROUP BY a, b;
```

You can't use aggregates with distinct, however, so if you're trying to get the max of a value, you will need to use GROUP BY.  I'm not sure exactly what your question is though

Comment: I don't know how to put the conditions, I would like something like IF PA1=O select * where PA1=0 group by PlotID ELSE select * where SightingID=max(SihtingID)

Answer (score 0):

Its not totally clear what you want. If you want to select the SightingID associated with the max Area of but want the record with PA1=0 first this is how you do it.

```
SELECT 
  case when maxPlotZero.Area is null then
          maxPlot.SightingID
        else 
          maxPlotZero.SightingID
  end SightingID

FROM 
 DF
 LEFT JOIN

 (

   SELECT 


         PlotID, 
         MAX(Area) Area
   FROM 
           DF
    WHERE
        PA1=0

    GROUP BY 
        PlotID
)  maxPlotZero

ON df.PlotId= maxPlotZero.PlotID
   and df.Area= maxPlotZero.Area
LEFT JOIN

(

SELECT 



         PlotID, 
         MAX(Area) 
FROM 
       DF

GROUP BY 
    PlotID
)  maxPlot

  ON df.PlotId= maxPlot.PlotID
   and df.Area= maxPlot.Area
```

Comment: I try to run the code and I have an error: (error in statement: near "maxPlot": syntax error). I'm running it from R with the sqldf package

Comment: Maybe there's something wrong with my data, I'll try to work on it but I get how I have to do it with the left join and the 2 conditions. Thanks a lot !

Comment: I fixed the data so maybe there is something that does not work in R

Comment: sqldf uses SQLite which uses the form CASE ... WHEN ... THEN so add the THEN . See http://www.sqlite.org/syntaxdiagrams.html#expr

Comment: @G. Grothendieck doh,  Thanks I fixed it.